# Invalid characters when creating a login

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to create a login from an asymmetric key via:

```
Create login [domain\username] from asymmetric key CLR_ExtensionKey
```

but sql server keeps telling me that:

```
'domain\username' is not a valid name because it contains invalid characters.
```

There are only letters in both the domain and username. Anyone know what's wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't create a windows login (in form `domain\username`) unless it's `from windows` as well. No backslash in SQL Server logins, AFAIK.

I don't understand what you're trying to do?

Comment: I have created an asymmetric key from a file and now I'm trying to connect my Windows login to that key. After that I would like to created an assembly from a .NET dll which is signed with such key. Does that make sense to you?

Comment: Actually it doesn't. Login is either mapped to your windows login or is mapped to a certificate, can't be both. It makes sense to sign something with a certificate though.